# How to do an inner join to get rid of dupes

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

How can I use an inner join to get rid of the dupes that I dont want?
The table I'm working on looks like this:

```
ID  Edited_date  Status
------------------------
1   1/1/2015     A    
1   1/1/2016     B    
1   2/1/2016     C    
2   1/1/2017     D     
2   3/1/2017     B     
3   1/1/2016     C    
3   4/1/2017     B    
3   1/1/2014     D
```

However, I only want the status of each loan from the most recent edited_date

```
ID  Edited_date  Status
------------------------
1   2/1/2016     C
2   3/1/2017     B 
3   4/1/2017     B
```

Comment: You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION BY` clause.

Comment: By "get rid of" you mean delete them or just exclude them from a select result? Also why the requirement for an inner join?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from [table] t1
inner join 
(
select ID, max(Edited_date) maxDt
from [Table]
group by ID
) t2
on t1.ID = t2.ID
and t1.Edited_date = t2.maxDt;
```

Answer (score 1):

For select only:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Edited_date desc) as Indicator
FROM TABLE_NAME
) as ABC
WHERE ABC.Indicator = 1
```

For delete:

```
WITH ABC
AS
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Edited_date desc) as Indicator
FROM TABLE_NAME
)
DELETE FROM ABC
WHERE ABC.Indicator != 1
```

Answer (score 1):

using [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) partitioned by `id` to get the latest `edited_date`

```
select id, edited_date, status
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (partition by id order by edited_date desc)
  from t
    ) as s
where rn = 1
```

[**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) version:

```
select top 1 with ties
    id
  , edited_date
  , status
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by edited_date desc)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Begin Transaction

Create table #temp (Id int, Edited_date date, Status char(2))

Insert into #temp
Values
('1','1/1/2015','A'),   
('1','1/1/2016','B'),  
('1','2/1/2016','C'),    
('2','1/1/2017','D'),      
('2','3/1/2017','B'),      
('3','1/1/2016','C'),     
('3','4/1/2017','B'),     
('3','1/1/2014','D')

Create table #temp2 (Id int, Edited_date date, Status char(2))

Insert into #temp2
Values
('1','2/1/2016','C'),
('2','3/1/2017','B'), 
('3','4/1/2017','B')

/** emphasis on the below **/

;with cte as (
Select max(Edited_date) as Edited_date, Status From #temp Group By Status
union all
Select max(Edited_date) as Edited_date, Status From #temp2 Group By Status
)

Select Status, max(Edited_date) as Recent_Edited_date From cte Group By Status

/** End of Emphasis **/

Drop table #temp
Drop table #temp2

Rollback

--- Result ---

Status| Recent_Edited_date

A|  2015-01-01    
B|  2017-04-01    
C|  2016-02-01    
D|  2017-01-01
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and use the markdown formatting tools to make your answers easier to read. Unfortunately, your answer A) Is not a general solution (it will only work for this dataset) and B) Doesn't give the results the OP requested.